# How could I increase the range of an HID axis? (steering wheel hits limit after a few degrees)

Tags: usb, simulation, stm32, hid, gamepad

I have an encoder that gives 4300 increments per rev. And I need at least 3 turns in either direction. (for a steering wheel)
However, when I turn it just a bit, it already hits the extremums. This is after a few degrees clockwise:

[image]

This is my descripor:

[image]

My code:

```
  while (1)
  {
      steer.direction = position - position_p;
      position_p = position;

      USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &steer, sizeof(steer));
      HAL_Delay(5);
  }
```

I have tried using an absolute value. With 8 bits it just overflows after a few degrees and comes back to the opposite extremum. Maybe 16 bits could solve that but I can't get it to work that way.

Comment: Just a note about physical units: they are meant to allow the device driver to convert the "logical" (i.e. no unit) numbers sent by the device into "physical" (real world) units like kilograms, metres, degrees etc. If your application does not need to see real world units then you could just code LOGICAL_MININIMUM -12900, LOGICAL_MAXIMUM 12900 and remove the PHYSICAL_xxx items from the descriptor. For a steering wheel I guess you may want to see the steering angle in degrees though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use a 16 bit absolute position.
I think it didn't work because the "send" function only took 8-bit values.
So I've split the 16 bit variable into a 2x8-bit array. (im using cubeIDE)

```
  steer.direction[0] = position & 0x00FF;
  steer.direction[1] = position >> 8;
```

[image]

Comment: Minor note: 65536 (0x10000) will not fit into a 16-bit field. You should code LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (65535) i.e. 27 FF FF 00 00